# Facebook SDK asking for permissions again and again like running in a loop in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am using Facebook SDK(latest version) in my app. I just want to take general data from the logged in user like name, date of birth, location, gender etc. and just want to fill the details accordingly. But the problem is that its showing the permission dialog again and again infinitely even I press Ok or Cancel for the app permission dialog its doing the same showing that permission dialog again and again. I cant understand whats wrong with this.

my login function is like this :-

```
    Session.openActiveSession(context, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(session.isOpened())
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please Wait", 1).show();
                List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();

                if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                    pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(context, PERMISSIONS);
                    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                }

                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(user!=null)
                        {

                            try{
                                Log.d("", "Fb responcse == "+response.toString());
                                Log.d("", "FbUser >> "+ user.toString());
                                fbUserid=user.getId();
                                fbAccessToken=session.getAccessToken();
                                Log.i("User Name ", "FbName : "+user.getName());
                                Log.i("User Id ", "FbId : "+user.getId());
                                Log.i("User Id ", "FbLocation : "+user.getLocation().toString());

                                Log.i("User Id ", "FbEmailId : "+user.getLink());
                                Log.i("User Id ", "FbDob : "+user.getBirthday());

                                Log.i("User Id ", "FbGender : "+user.asMap().get("gender").toString());
                                Log.i("User Id ", "FbEmail : "+user.getProperty("email").toString());
                                //Log.i("User Id ", "FbCity : "+user.getLocation().getCity().toString());
                                //Log.i("User Id ", "FbState : "+user.getLocation().getState().toString());
                                Log.i("User Access Token ", "FbAccess Token : "+session.getAccessToken());
                                pBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                String name = user.getName();
                                String dob = user.getBirthday();
                                String gender = user.asMap().get("gender").toString();
                                String email =user.getProperty("email").toString();
                                String city = user.getLocation().getProperty("name").toString();
                                String url="http://graph.facebook.com/"+user.getId()+"/picture?type=large";
                                setText(name, dob, email, city, "","",url);
                            }catch(Exception ex){
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        }

                        else{
                            pBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Log.i("ELSE", "ELSE");
                        }
                    }


                });

            }


        }


    });
```

Also I am using permission to get these details using this code snippet :-

```
List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions","email","user_birthday","user_location");
```

Please help me to sort out this, as it is again and again showing me the permission dialog only.

Any help would be appreciable thanks in advance

Comment: Once you request the `session.requestNewPublishPermissions()` the callback method `call()` of `Session.StatusCallback()` will be invoked again. 

Then you enter `session.isOpened()` and it looks like `isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)` returns **false** every time. Thus, you ask again for permissions, and again and again...

Comment: Do you resolve this problem? I am stuck with it too!

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @sromku Can you help me too ? I have similar login problem (it loops): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978044/facebook-android-sdk-login-loop

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened())
            {
                List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

                if (!session.getPermissions().containsAll(PERMISSIONS))
                {
                    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(ActivityRegistration.this, PERMISSIONS);
                    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                }

                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            Log.i("Facebook Welcome " + user.getName());
                            compileWithFacebookInfo(user);
                        }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            }
        }
    });
```

I think that issue is "email", "user_birthday", "user_location" : are 
    session.requestNewReadPermissions(...);

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me when Facebook is installed. The web dialog that is used when Facebook is not installed behaves correctly.

Comment: @Dimentar can you help me too ? My problem is similar loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978044/facebook-android-sdk-login-loop

Answer (score 0):

We also suffered from this problem. The solution was to check permission names. If one of the permission names is wrong (e.g. depricated) then session.requestNewPublishPermissions(..) calls the callback method call() of Session.StatusCallback() again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem having the Facebook application installed. I think SSO (Sigle Sign On) used by default to authenticate the session is the cause of that "loop".

To solve the problem add the to your `newPermissionRequest` the flag to suppress the SSO:

```
Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(context, PERMISSIONS);
newPermissionsRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
```